# WP CLI not importing media files

Tags: import, wp-cli

When I tried on localhost, it appears media files are imported. When I tried on real server (AWS LightSail) seems like images are not imported why might it be? I did not ask it to `--skip`

The main difference I see is for local one, I used `wp core install` etc to install the WP. For the server one the install is already done by LightSail/Bitnami. Does this make a difference? I do not expect it to?

`wp import something.xml --authors=mapping.csv --path=./`

Comment: Is it possible to upload media through wordpress dashboard on this remote server? What is the message from wp cli when you try to import?

Comment: What is the exact line you run?

Comment: @prosti updated post

Comment: @MateuszMarchel, at the end a success message `Success: Finished importing from 'something.xml' file.` so its OK? Posts are imported just that images are still linked to old site

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly: You have exported wordpress posts and now you want to import this via wp-cli but links to images have wrong urls? Is it correct? 
At first I understand that you have problem with media importing (wp media import).

Comment: @MateuszMarchel, your understanding is correct, but the command does not seem to do what I need. It seems like its more like an upload image function http://wp-cli.org/commands/media/import/

Comment: Yep, I just misunderstood at first. Can you check if the images are uploaded to the server? If yes then probably you just need to do search and replace on the database which you can easily do with wp cli. http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/

Comment: Where are you generating the xml file from?

Comment: @MateuszMarchel, nope no images

Comment: @czerspalace, wordpress.com

Answer (score 1):

> wp import something.xml

The possible problem with this solution is when the original domain is not available from the web server you are on. Try to `ping` the domain name from the AWS LightSail.

You know for the `wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/demo/theme-unit-test-data.xm‌l`, there you have images like `wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/manhattansummer.‌​jpg`, but when the domain `wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com` is not available anymore the whole thing with resources will not work.

---

Also do you get some feedback of success / failure like this

```
# Import content from a WXR file
$ wp import example.wordpress.2016-06-21.xml --authors=create
Starting the import process...
Processing post #1 ("Hello world!") (post_type: post)
-- 1 of 1
-- Tue, 21 Jun 2016 05:31:12 +0000
-- Imported post as post_id #1
Success: Finished importing from 'example.wordpress.2016-06-21.xml' file.
```

---

Finally if you try to `wget` some image from your origianal website what you will get?

Something like this but on your domain.

```
 wget wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/manhattansummer.‌​jpg
```

Comment: i didn't understand any of this:  how's it related to domains?  does "wp import" not taking local (i.e. on the server) files?  which domain do you need to provide, AND WHY?